# How to .search() multiple strings and have at least 1 to then do function?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm programming a calculator for my final high school math project and I can't seem to find how to .search() multiple strings and if the element has at least one then it will work.

```
    function pie(val) {
  var pi = document.getElementById("display").value.search("/" | "*" | "-" | "+");
  if (pi != -1) {
    document.getElementById("display").value += val;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("display").value = "Please add an operator";
}
}
```

I want Pi to only execute if there's an operator because if there's none it just adds PI to whatever number is on the screen.

```js
// Clear Function
function c(val) {
  document.getElementById("display").value = val;
}
// Insert Number Function
function insert(val) {
  document.getElementById("display").value += val;
}
// Equal Function
function equal(val) {
  try {
    c(eval(document.getElementById("display").value))
  }
catch(equal) {
    document.getElementById("display").value = "error";
    }
}
// Root Function
function root(val) {
  var vroot = document.getElementById("display").value;
  var rooted = Math.sqrt(document.getElementById("display").value);
  var r = document.getElementById("display").value = rooted;

if (vroot< 0) {
    document.getElementById("display").value= "no";
  }
}
// Pie Fonction
function pie(val) {
  var pi = document.getElementById("display").value.search("/" | "*" | "-" | "+");
  if (pi != -1) {
    document.getElementById("display").value += val;
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("display").value = "Please add an operator";
}
}
// Power function : fix so power of any number
function power(val) {
  var base = document.getElementById("display").value;
  document.getElementById("display").value = base * base;
}
// Log Function
function log(val) {
  var vlog = document.getElementById("display").value;
  var vloged = Math.log(document.getElementById("display").value);
  var v = document.getElementById("display").value = vloged;
  if (vlog < 0) {
    document.getElementById("display").value= "no";
  }
}

function cos(val) {
  var vroot = document.getElementById("display").value;
  var rooted = Math.sqrt(document.getElementById("display").value);
  var r = document.getElementById("display").value = "√" + vroot + "=" + rooted;
}

function sin(val) {
  var vroot = document.getElementById("display").value;
  var rooted = Math.sqrt(document.getElementById("display").value);
  var r = document.getElementById("display").value = "√" + vroot + "=" + rooted;
}

function tan(val) {
  var vroot = document.getElementById("display").value;
  var rooted = Math.sqrt(document.getElementById("display").value);
  var r = document.getElementById("display").value = "√" + vroot + "=" + rooted;
}
```

```css
.calculator {
text-align: center;
}
.display input {
  margin-left: 5px;
  font-size: 50px;
  width: 600px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: rgb(217, 217, 217);
  border-color: rgb(230,230,230, .5);
  color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
  margin-top: 25px;
}

.display input:focus {
  outline:0;
}

.button {
  background-color: rgb(230, 230, 230, .5);
  font-size: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin:3px;
  color: rgb(153, 153, 153);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: rgb(230,230,230, .5);
}
.button:hover {
background-color: white;
}

.button:focus {
  outline:0;
}

body {
  background-color: rgb(204, 204, 204);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Calculator </title>
</head>
<body>


<div class="calculator">
<div class="display">
  <input type="text" id="display">
</div>
<div class="main">
    <br>
    <center>
<table>
  <tr>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="C" onclick='c("")'></td>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="π" onclick='pie(Math.PI)'></td>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="√" onclick='root()'></td>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="^" onclick='power()'></td>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="*" onclick='insert("*")'></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="log" onclick='log()'></td>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="7" onclick='insert(7)'></td>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="8" onclick='insert(8)'></td>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="9" onclick='insert(9)'></td>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="/" onclick='insert("/")'></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="cos" onclick='cos()'></td>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="4" onclick='insert(4)'></td>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="5" onclick='insert(5)'></td>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="6" onclick='insert(6)'></td>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="+" onclick='insert("+")'></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="sin" onclick='sin()'></td>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="1" onclick='insert(1)'></td>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="2" onclick='insert(2)'></td>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="3" onclick='insert(3)'></td>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="-" onclick='insert("-")'></td>
</tr>

<tr>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="tan" onclick='tan()'></td>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="?" onclick='insert("")'></td>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="0" onclick='insert(0)'></td>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="." onclick='insert(".")'></td>
  <td><input type="button" class="button" value="=" onclick='equal()'></td>
</tr>
</table>
</center>
</div>


</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The stuff passed to a search method `document.getElementById("display").value.search("/" | "*" | "-" | "+")` doesn't work as you may expect. It's a bitwise or operator, and is a part of boolean arithmetic haha :)

Comment: [`search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) takes a regular expression. If you are looking for any of those, use `/[\/*+-]/` as the parameter to `search`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

search takes a regular expression. If you are looking for any of those, use /[/*+-]/ as the parameter to search. – Mike McCaughan

He commented it so I don't know how to make it so he solved the question.

Answer (score 2):

Try to rewrite this line

```
var pi = document.getElementById("display").value.search("/" | "*" | "-" | "+");
```

To this:

```
 var pi = ["/", "*", "-", "+"].indexOf(document.getElementById("display").value);
```

Comment: It still triggers the else statement when there's numbers on the display

Answer (score 0):

You should use Array.some for this.

It will return true if your value matches any one of the values from Array else false.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some